# ASP C# Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a function(PopulateStudents) that populates a dropdownlist with results from a database.  This function is called on two different occasions:  When a query string with id is provided, and in an onselectedindexchanged event.  Basically, if an ID is provided from the URL, then get a database record of a student's ID, which contains semesterID and courseID.  Then, all DDLs are populated based on the studentID.

If there is no ID in the URL, the user selects a semester from a DDL.  Then the course DDL is populated based on the semester ID selected in the semester DDL.  Then, the student DDL is populated based on the selected course.

The problem is that the PopulateStudent function works fine when no ID is provided in the query string and the user has to select the semester and then course.  When the ID is provded in the query string, the PopulateStudents function does not work.  The function throws an error that says `Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed.` What is wrong with my code?

Here is the aspx.cs file:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
                {
                    GetStudentScores(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]));

                    string connString;
                    connString = RetrieveConnectionString();

                    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

                    try
                    {
                        using (conn)
                        {
                            conn.Open();
                            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetEnrolleeDetails", conn);
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@enrollmentID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
                            cmd.Parameters["@enrollmentID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);

                            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                            reader.Read();

                            int semesterID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["semesterId"]);
                            int courseID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["courseId"]);

                            PopulateCourses(semesterID);
                            PopulateStudents(courseID);

                            DDSemester.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(semesterID);
                            DDCourse.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(courseID);
                            DDStudent.SelectedValue = Request.QueryString["ID"];
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception err)
                    {
                        lblStatus.Text = err.Message;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                        conn.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected void DDCourse_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                PopulateStudents(Convert.ToInt32(DDCourse.SelectedValue));
            }
        }



        protected void DDStudent_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                GetStudentScores(Convert.ToInt32(DDStudent.SelectedValue));
            }
        }

        protected void DDSemester_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                PopulateCourses(Convert.ToInt32(DDSemester.SelectedValue));
            }
        }

        private void PopulateCourses(int semesterID)
        {
            string connString;
            connString = RetrieveConnectionString();

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

            try
            {
                using (conn)
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetSemesterCourses", conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@semesterID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
                    cmd.Parameters["@semesterID"].Value = semesterID;

                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    DDCourse.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    DDCourse.DataTextField = "courseName";
                    DDCourse.DataValueField = "courseId";
                    DDCourse.DataBind();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                lblStatus.Text = err.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private void PopulateStudents(int courseID)
        {
            string connString;
            connString = RetrieveConnectionString();

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

            try
            {
                using (conn)
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.CourseEnrollment", conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@courseId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
                    cmd.Parameters["@courseId"].Value = courseID;

                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    DDStudent.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    DDStudent.DataTextField = "fullName";
                    DDStudent.DataValueField = "enrollmentId";
                    this.DataBind();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                lblStatus.Text = err.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Here is the asp:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Semester:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDSemester" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="semesterName" DataValueField="semesterId" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDSemester_SelectedIndexChanged">       
                <asp:ListItem Text="Select a Semester"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList><br />

    <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text="Course:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDCourse" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDCourse_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Select a Course"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList><br />

    <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Text="Student"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDStudent" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDStudent_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Select a Student"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList><br />
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You should only create your connections within the scope of the using statement e.g. `using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString) {`. That way, you don't need any of those manual close/dispose calls. May not be the solution, but it should help a little by simplifying your code. Same applies to any Reader objects and SqlCommands. Basically, anywhere you can use a using statement here, do so :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was actually one difference between the PopulateCourses and PopulateStudents functions that I didn't notice.  In courses, I used DDCourse.DataBind() and in students I used this.DataBind().

In the populatestudents function, changing this.DataBind() to DDStudent.DataBind() fixed my problem.